# Working on a Practice problem, don't want the answer just guidance towads figuring it out

Tags: python

So in the book automate the boring stuff chapter 4 the first project question is assume you have a list  in which `spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats]`

write a function that takes a list value as an arguement and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with the word "and" before the last item. This function should work for any list passed to it

For the code I am writing

```
def list():
    for i in range(len(list)-1):
        print(' ,' + ' , and' + list[-1])     

spam = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']
list = spam
print(spam)
```

I can get the comma and space to appear, but I cannot think of how to have the last value always have and before it

I have also tried

```
def list():
    for i in range(len(list)-1):
        print(' ,')
    for i[-1]
        print(, and' + list[-1])    

spam = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']
list = spam
print(spam)
```

Both don't work

I am not looking for someone to tell me what the code is but rather where my thinking is wrong and how I should frame it.

Thank You!

Comment: Rename your function to something else apart from `list` since it's a reserved python builtin name

Comment: To call your function, you must do `list(spam)`. However, as stated, you should rename it to something else.

Comment: Also look at `str.join`

Comment: Notice two more things: in your prints you are not actually printing any elements, just commas except the last one; You are not calling your function. simply printing the original list. Function calls are usually of the form: `func(arg1, arg2, ...)`

Comment: Thank you it seems I misunderstood functions, this clears it up and helps me to better understand

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below codes please.

```
def f(arg):
    string = ""
    for i in range(len(arg)):
        if i != len(arg) - 1:
            string += f"{arg[i]}, "
        else:
            string += f"and {arg[i]}"
    return string   


spam = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']

print(f(spam))
```

Output:

```
'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the " marks and the { automate the boring stuff hasn't used quotes or the { brackets yet

Comment: The brackets are used for string formatting. It is called f-string. And I wanted to return a string data to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to python, so I am not including the possible answers using methods the book has not covered yet. Looking at your code:

```
def list():
    for i in range(len(list)-1):
        print(' ,' + ' , and' + list[-1])     

spam = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']
list = spam
print(spam)
```

When your code comes time to print, it is actually printing the list reference, it is not printing the list as a string. You wrote a function:

```
def list():
    for i in range(len(list)-1):
        print(' ,' + ' , and' + list[-1])
```

But then you never pass anything to it and you never even call the function in the rest of your code:

```
spam = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']
list = spam
print(spam)
```

All you are doing here is defining the variable **spam** to store the list reference, then storing the variable **spam** in another variable **list** then printing **spam**...so you aren't even using the **list** variable

I suggest you use the Python Visualization tool at [pythontutor.com](https://pythontutor.com) it has really helped me. With that said, since you did not want the actual answer or code, I will give you the thought process I went through:

Step 1: *Define a function* that  will *take a list value as an argument* and *return a string* will all the items separated by a comma and a space, with the *'and' inserted before the last item.*

1. Your function is going to need an argument that will accept the list parameter and pass it into the function

   ```
     def functionName(argument):
        [code goes here]
   ```
2. Create a new variable that will hold the list values as a string. Since you have not parsed through the list yet to obtain that data this should probably be an empty variable.
3. Find what the length of the list is(taking into account it needs to accept any list length not just the example). From the length of the list, return that length's sequence of numbers, starting from 0, and increment it by one(HINT: there is a built in function that will do both of these)
4. Create a way that when the above code is running though the sequence it checks to see if the list index is the last index. If it is the last index in the list, concatenate 'and ' to that index, store it a variable(the one you created in Step 2) and increment so it will move to the next list index. Else, if it is not the last index in the list, concatenate that index and ', ', store it in a variable (the one you created in Step 2) and increment so it move to the next list index.
5. Once your code has gone through the entire list, have it return the value (while figuring out the code I used print() instead of return just so I could see the output on the screen.

Once you get this working so that it will take in any list or list length:

```
    spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']  
    spam2 = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats', 'monkeys', 'zebras', 'donkeys']
```

and return the list as a comma separated string with 'and' before the last index

```
apples, bananas, tofu, and cats
apples, bananas, tofu, cats, monkeys, zebras, and donkeys
```

Once you have your code doing this successfully you can move on to the part that stumped me for some time:
    "But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it."

Now you need to alter your function so that it will go through the list, if the list contains strings, it will run though as normal, but if the list contains integers, it needs to run though the same processes but convert the integers into strings so it will print out the list in the same manner

```
numbers  = [1, 2, 3, 4]
numbers2 = [1, 2, 3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and return the list as a comma separated string with 'and' before the last index

```
1, 2, 3, and 4
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8, 9, and 10
```